# Problem while saving a CSS file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

First of all, I apologize for my bad English.

When I save a file with CSS in Visual Studio Code I get a problem. The text in the file flashes and sometimes the text moves in sideways. I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code but the same error occurs.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never had that problem come up. This may be something that is better suited for the VSCode team.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter where you save the file? Also, a screen recording would greatly help understanding the problem. You can make a screen recording for free with https://screencast-o-matic.com/screen_recorder